# How to write a function that can load R package, if this package is not installed, install it automatically

Tags: r, package, installation

Since I work on different PCs with same script, I always need to install packages, thus my package loading argument is always `if(!require("ggplot2")){install.packages("ggplot2"); library(ggplot2)}` (ggplot2 as an example).

So I want to write a function as the title describes, my thought was

`load_packages <- function(package){
if(!require(package)){install.packages(package); library(package)}
}`

however despite it can install package through `load_packages("ggplot2")`, it can't load as it says

`Error in library(package) : there is no package called ‘package’`

Comment: Use `character.only=TRUE` in call to `library`? Because then `library` will evaluate `package` and not take it as the name of a package. See`?library`.

Comment: `if(!require(pkg,character.only =TRUE)){install.packages(pkg);require(pkg,character.only =TRUE)}`

Comment: Why not use the pacman::p_load() function ? The pacman package is quite an efficient package manager !